# How to I simplify this to a single fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

[image]
I don't know how to fully simplify this and get rid of the seven at the end. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{7a+7b}{8a}-\frac{9a+3b}{2a}+7 = \frac{7a+7b}{8a}-\frac{36a+12b}{8a}+\frac{56a}{8a}=\frac{7a+7b-(36a+12b)+56a}{8a} = \frac{7a+7b-36a-12b+56a}{8a}= \frac{27a-5b}{8a}$$

Comment: Hey George, I'm wondering where the +7 at the end went? If you could explain that would be awesome. Thank you

Comment: $$ 7 = \frac{56a}{8a}$$

Comment: Thank you George!